# Updating SQL Table from Two Column Excel SpreadSheet

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, excel-formula

My first post:

Looking for some help. I need to update multiple databases I have a SQL database with a Vehicle Table within that table is a serial number field (VarChar) usually contains a unique number. Unique  is not correct.

I am able to get a spreadsheet containing all the Unique numbers in Column A and then what that VarChar field should be in Column B

So SQL Database might look like

**Vehicle Table**

| Serial |
| --- |
| 11212 |
| 12333 |
| 23332 |

**My Excel Spreadsheet**

| SQL Match | SQL Update |
| --- | --- |
| 11212 | A43000203 |
| 12333 | A1203995 |
| 23332 | G88929 |

I have about 600 rows of these per database with over 30 databases to do... what is my easiest solution with limited DBA rights?

I would like to just do updates. I thought about PowerShell script, importing into a table and write a replace type script would be easier if I could just call from excel say:

Update tVehicle
set serial = {Excel Spread Sheet [ SQL Update]}
where serial = {Excel Spread Sheet [SQL Match]}

Thanks for any thoughts or help...

Thought about PowerShell but I am not sure how to script it, I need to do this with various spreadsheets about 30 times so I need to make it easily repeatable. I also thought about importing the two column data into a temp table but I am not sure I have enough rights to do that... looking more for a find the match and replace it hopefully just using my two column spreadsheet and I can switch the data source as I switch databases.

I dont want to use merge because it is one field of many I just want to update the field where I find to equal the value in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would never put this in production, but if I were doing something quick and dirty that I had complete control over, I would use ADO in VBA to execute update statements.

```
Public Sub UpdateVehNum()
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sSql As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Connection STring"
    
    For Each rCell In Selection.Cells
        sSql = "UPDATE Vehicles SET Serial = '" & rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & "' WHERE Serial = '" & rCell.Value & "'"
        cn.Execute sSql
    Next rCell
    
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out, it's only for a 1-time update... test it with my backup first.